# In Ansible, how to apply a scalar filter to a list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to apply an ansible filter to each element in a list, then create a string from it. So lets say I have a list

```
my_files:
    - /etc/passwd
    - /etc/group
```

And then in an ansible task I want to create a string like "passwd,group". Without the filtering, this can be done with the jinja syntax

```
{{ ",".join(my_files) }}
```

which would create a string "/etc/passwd,/etc/group". But now I want to apply the ansible basename filter to each element. For a scalar this works like

```
{{ /etc/passwd | basename }}
```

which would generate the string "passwd". So the question is, how to combine these two operations to generate the string "passwd,group" from the list my_files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a map reduce pattern to achieve that. You would first map each entry using a `basename` filter and then join the resulting list.

The following playbook demonstrates how this can be done:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_files:
      - /etc/passwd
      - /etc/group

  tasks:
    - name: MapReduce
      debug:
        msg: "{{ my_files | map('basename') | list | join(',')}}" # results in passwd,group
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!